# iked mutex lock issue

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec

On Ubuntu 15.04, fresh install of the `ike` package with these requirements installed:
`cmake libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui libedit-dev libssl-dev checkinstall flex bison`

results in:

```
$ sudo iked
iked: pthread_mutex_unlock.c:87: __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt: Assertion `type == PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP' failed.

$ uname -a
Linux miranda 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have attempted to downgrade the package, gcc, etc. no luck. Any ideas why this error is occuring.

journalctl -u ike:

```
May 29 08:00:26 miranda systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Shrew Soft IKE Daemon...
May 29 08:00:26 miranda ike[2452]: iked: pthread_mutex_unlock.c:87: __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt: Assertion `type == PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP' failed.
May 29 08:00:26 miranda ike[2452]: Aborted (core dumped)
May 29 08:00:26 miranda systemd[1]: Started LSB: Shrew Soft IKE Daemon.
```

Comment: "Assertion _anything_ failed" means your first stop should be to the developer's bug reporting facility.

Comment: Fresh install of Debian Jessie on a VMware VM, I'm now getting this error. Did you have any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Just installed OpenIKED on fresh Ubuntu 15.04 x64 installation. Works fine for me and has no issue you've mentioned.

You may try to find some clues in system log, where errors reported: `journalctl -e`.
It helped me to find out that I don't have valid configuration, though `sudo iked` exited with zero code.

```
May 28 04:55:07 iked-test iked[5235]: parent[5235]: /usr/local/etc/iked.conf: no valid configuration rules found
May 28 04:55:07 iked-test iked[5237]: ikev2[5237]: ikev2 exiting
```

Examples from `iked.conf(5)` helped to get rid of it.

Also, did you followed these steps from installation manual?

```
mkdir /var/empty
chown root:root /var/empty
chmod 755 /var/empty
groupadd iked
useradd -g iked -c 'iked privsep' -d /var/empty -s /sbin/nologin iked
```

(I changed group/user name from `_iked` to follow Linux style)

Comment: yes, I followed the directions and have checked logs, no help.

Comment: that is `openiked` as well, I am installing `ike` package from apt.

Comment: @Michael have you tried to update packages like libc to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.vpn.shrew.user/3970

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756316

this bugs appears sometimes; its reason seems unknown.

Comment: That is my bug report and my issue, so it is known to me ;)

Comment: The first link is yours but the second one (debian bug) is not; right?
You should add your link to your question and I'll erase it from my answer